# Fancybox: Getting it to work on mouseover/mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I currently have it working halfway by using:

```
jQuery("a.lightbox").fancybox().hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).click();
  }, function() {
    jQuery("#fancybox-overlay").click();
  });
```

When I hover over the thumbnail it works fine, but when I mouseover the background, `#fancybox-overlay` it doesnt disable fancybox.. any ideas?

with hoverIntent:

```
function openFancybox(){
 jQuery(this).trigger("click");
}
function closeFancybox(){
 jQuery.fancybox.close();
}

jQuery("a.lightbox").hoverIntent({
 sensitivity: 100,
 interval:250,
 timeout:0,
 over: openFancybox,
 out: closeFancybox 
}); // hoverIntent

jQuery("#fancybox-content img").hoverIntent({
 sensitivity: 10,
 interval:500,
 timeout:0,
// over: openFancybox,
 out: closeFancybox 
}); // hoverIntent

jQuery("a.lightbox").fancybox({
 'overlayShow' : false,
 'autoScale'   : true
}); // fancybox
```

Comment: make a fiddle: [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and people will help you

Comment: @yckart I'm using wordpress so not sure how to duplicate what I have, im using this theme: http://demo.themezilla.com/?theme=gridlocked if that helps any

Comment: Can you give then the link to your page, please? That will help us more!

Comment: there was a similar question with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11731165/1055987 that may help to solve your issue.

Comment: @JFK thank you! I edited my main post with what I have so far.  the hoverIntent works, but sometimes when fancybox pops up it pops up under the mouse and when the mouse isn't over the image that pops up it doesnt go away unless the X is clicked.  I tried to fix it by editing your code but probably didnt do it correctly and I wasnt sure if I should use `#fancybox-content` or `#fancybox-content img`, both didn't work but I might be close to what I need.. could you take a look and reply as an answer so I can mark your answer as the one that worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer:

**HTML**

```
<a href="image1.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="gallery"><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
<a href="image2.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="gallery"><img src="image2.jpg"></a>​
```

**JS**

```
$("a.lightbox").fancybox({
    'showCloseButton': false
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
    $(".fancybox-overlay").mouseout(function() {
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NvpVT/1/)**

Comment: is there any way for the image that pops up to stay while the mouse is over the actual image?

Comment: the main problem when working with `.hover` is called "bubbling"

Comment: Using the js from ickart, I get this error: SyntaxError: illegal character

}); Any help to solve the chained function(fancybox, hover) call problem ? It would be good to have the code commented. What is this.click() doing?​

Comment: @Timo can you provide us a bit of your actual state? It's hard to see where your problem sits... The `.click()`  triggers a click event on `a.lightbox` http://api.jquery.com/click/#click

Answer (score 0):

use this snippet:

```
$("a.lightbox").mouseover(function(){
   $("a.lightbox:first").trigger("click");
});
```

do the same with mouseout event ... =)

Comment: it displays one image, but it doesn't work for other images on the page