# JQuery Fancybox open delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fancybox, delay

I have a fancybox for displaying photos and descriptions of them.
Now it opens fancybox on mouseenter event. It works perfectly with this code:

```
$('.fancy_link').live('mouseenter', mouseEnter);
function mouseEnter()
{
jQuery(this).fancybox().trigger('click');
return false;
}
```

But i need to set delay for opening fancybox. How it should work: **User moves cursor over a link, after 1 second fancybox should open and display content. If user moves mouse away before waiting 1 second, fancybox should not open.**

I have tried JQuery delay() and setTimeout() but both of them are not working properly.
One sec. delay just ignored by both methods.

Comment: You may want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11731165/1055987

Comment: It looks like you're trying to delay a hover trigger which is quite tricky as it re-fires at the slightest movement of the mouse. The link in the comment is helpful, but also, look at the 'hoverintent' plugin (Google it) very helpful and I think would completely handle what you need.

Comment: @JamieHartnoll: the link in my comment also includes the link to the `hoverIntent` plugin and a code sample of how to use it. @crd: the possible issue with the accepted answer is called "bubbling" if you know what I mean (this is where `hoverIntent` becomes handy). Also `live()` is deprecated and the reason it may not be working with `on()` is because both methods don't have necessarily the same structure (`on()` should have a delegated form in this case); @tracker1 should provide you with the right `.on()` delegated format since his answer was accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setTimeout/clearTimeout...

```
//binding code...
$('.fancy_link').on('mouseenter',mouseEnter);
$('.fancy_link').on('mouseleave', mouseLeave);

//run when the mouse hovers over the item
function mouseEnter() {
  //clear any previous timer
  clearTimeout($(this).data('h_hover'));

  //get a reference to the current item, for the setTimeout callback
  var that = this;

  //set a timer, and save the reference to g_hover
  var h_hover = setTimeout(function(){
    //timer timed out - click the item being hovered
    $(that).click();
  }, 1000);

  //save the reference - attached to the item - for clearing
  //  data is a generic "store", it isn't saved to the tag in the dom.
  //  note: if you have a data-* attribute it is readable via data()
  $(this).data('h_hover',h_hover)
}

//handler for when the mouse leaves the item
function mouseLeave() {
  //clear the previously set timeout
  clearTimeout($(this).data('h_hover'));
}
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` instead with jQuery v1.7+

Comment: Thanks! it's working perfectly. But only with method `live()`. With method `on()` function `mouseEnter()` does not executes.

Comment: Not sure who down-voted me, but if you could add a comment when you down vote as to why, it would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
var timer = null;
$('.fancy_link').on('mouseenter', function() {
    timer = setTimeout(mouseEnter, 1000);
});
// clear timer when mouse leaves
$('.fancy_link').on('mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. In jquery.min.js v1.7.2 on line 583 error: return a.nodeName && a.nodeName.toUpperCase() === b.toUpperCase() — Unhandled Error: Security error: attempted to read protected variable: nodeName. When i'm trying to open fancybox immediately without delay error not occurs.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` instead with jQuery v1.7+

Comment: No effect at all. Now function mouseEnter is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

this could help you

```
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {$('#fancy_link').trigger('click'); },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you will need to use setTimeout and clearTimeout

Something along these lines:

```
var timer;

$('.fancy_link').mouseenter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $this.fancybox().trigger('click');
    }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```