# Creating a tooltip with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am trying to create a tooltip using Fancybox 2.0. When the user hovers the mouse over the question mark image, the tooltip should popup.

The code I have so far is this:

HTML:

```
<a id="meque" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="/images/question.png" alt="question" /></a>

<div class="newTitle" style="display: none;"><p>hello, visite my site <a href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/">http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/</a></p></div>
```

JQUERY :

```
jQuery("#meque").fancybox({
         openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            arrows :    false,
            beforeShow : function() {
            this.title = jQuery(".newTitle div").eq(this.index).html();
            }  
 }); // fancybox
```

Nothing happens when the image is hover or clicked. Any ideas to unstuck?

Comment: I would rather use a tooltip plugin instead, but if you really  want to use fancybox then check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11731165/1055987 if that helps (includes demo)